# Node converting Array to String in JSON request

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I am sending the JSON request to the Node.js API.

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "userId":1002,
        "type":"from",
        "actors": [1001],
        "actual_amount":5.00,
        "last_modified":1421480903128
    },
    success : function(data) {
        //Success
    },
    error : function(err) {
        //Error
    }
});
```

Request Obj received in Node.API :

```
actors: "[1001]"
actual_amount: "5.00"
last_modified: "1421480903128"
type: "from"
userId: "1002"



var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Please let me know how to resolve this. I am new to Node.js

Comment: Is your question simply how to convert an array into string? - `JSON.stringify`. Or are you experiencing a problem doing so?

Comment: I am getting the req.body as an JSON object but the value of actors is String. Its should be an array as i am sending in the AJAX request.

Comment: Even numbers got converted to String.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `JSON.stringify` your `data` object so that it's sent as JSON instead of just a string of key=value parameters:

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "userId":1002,
        "type":"from",
        "actors": [1001],
        "actual_amount":5.00,
        "last_modified":1421480903128
    }),
    success : function(data) {
        //Success
    },
    error : function(err) {
        //Error
    }
});
```